# What difference does anchor peers make in fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I removed anchor peer definition in configtx.yaml file and also I didn't update anchor peers on my channel for any participating orgs. Surprisingly, the network works fine and all transactions are going through.

I made changes in fabric-samples/first-network folder of fabric's official github repo. I understand that anchor peers are used for gossip communication and peer discovery, though having no anchor peer in the network made no visible difference as compared to when we define  them. I was hoping to see some errors but none came. How do I gauge difference between both cases ?

Answer (score 3):

You need anchor peers in order to allow cross organizations communication, that's mean to make peers from different organization domain able to get connected. Now, normally in each organization gossip elects peer to serve as a leader to pull blocks from ordering service and gossip them around. Therefore if no anchor peers is configured, most likely you won't see any difference.

Now, the question, why do you need them. Here is two reasons

1. You need cross organization communication during state transfer or replication of missing blocks in case for example where one org partitioned from the ordering service but can reach out to the other organization.
2. Second use case if more complex one. You need cross organization communication for private data, as private data distributed off chain, e.g. via gossip. You need to be able to push pieces of private data during endorsement. And pull missing private data during commit.

Hence unless you are not encounter a need of any of these two scenarios you won't feel any difference with or without anchor peers configured.